# Facebook app: Cannot add a domain in my app

Tags: facebook

For a few weeks I've been getting the error "Async request failed with error 1007" when I try to add a domain to my app.

when requesting /apps/ApplicationIdentifier/async/domain/add/

[image]

Comment: Can you change the error message to English?